# Как отключить вывод инклюдов MSVC?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

При сборке проекта CMake, делая сборку проекта, в окне сборке показывает полные пути включения файлов

```
Примечание: включение файла:             C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore/qatomic.h
Примечание: включение файла:        C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui/qfont.h
Примечание: включение файла:        C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui/qfontmetrics.h
Примечание: включение файла:        C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui/qfontinfo.h
Примечание: включение файла:        C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets/qsizepolicy.h
```

я хотел бы вырубить эту опцию

Comment: этот флаг называется /showIncludes как его вырубить?

Comment: судя по форумам - никак.

Comment: я поменял нинзю на чет другое) и все заработало)